# Subdivision Surface modifier breaks animated objects

Tags: modeling, animation

First of all, Hello World!

I’m fresh and started to learn Blender on my own (with documentation saved offline). I am working at sea, and basically have very limited internet access - I can forget about tutorials and so on until I get home within two months.

As I wanted to try model something more complicated I decided to do anchor. It is created from technical data, and it is actual real anchor we use here. Anchor itself consists of two elements - vertical long center piece with hole on each end. Bottom hole serves as connection for second part of anchor with flukes (fangs), basically it’s like pipe passing through this hole to enable rotation later. That’s because those two elements should be able to create 40 deg angle both ways while still being connected. Well anyway model was created and looks ok.

Problem started when I wanted to try (just for fun) and animate it. With any level of Subdivision Surface both of those elements disconnects on impact, while without it and with changing scale, mass, boinciness etc. it works ok? So should I not use Subsurf to animate or may it be that model causes problem?

Cant upload pics with this speed so I would be glad for slightest possibilities or suspicions ;)

I added 3 pics, before applying Mirror and assembling two pieces together, after inserting cylindrical part into hole, and wireframe of this connection. After starting animation the stake jumps out, unless I turn off subsurf. Also collision Sensitivity must be 0, I tried with 0.001, and the effect was same, maybe slightly less drastic, playing with Bounciness and Friction tends to change effects. I use Final and Mesh colliders.

[image][image][image]

Comment: try applying the subdivision modifier

Comment: I tried, it does some weird things to my model, but thanks to that I can delete double vertices (wonder why Remove Doubles doesn’t work). Anyhow this doesn’t seem to work as well. I’ll try to play with accurate placement, maybe there is some part intersecting that I can’t see or masses are incorrect.

Comment: Could you please add images to your question to help explain the issue?

Comment: Added what I could with this internet.